# How to fix "Unable to unserialize value. Error: Syntax error" Magento 2.3.2

Tags: magento2, php-7.2, unserialize

**Hello, Guys!**

I get this error, please help me solve it...

[image]

[image]

[image]

**String value:**

> a:1:{s:14:"logotype_image";s:57:"/frontend/Alias/mysite/web/images/logo_grey.svg";}

And 
**json_last_error = 4**

The string value comes from the database.

How to fix it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Magento change serialization from php to json in 2.1 version.

Looks like you have some data in database is not converted to proper format for some reason.

So, you need to convert co it manually to fix problem.

Comment: Thank you very much! I relied on Magento and did not notice this problem)